# Version control practices - interal class specific versions

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a reasonably small project that I would like to put under version control (Subversion + Tortoise). Currently, I am using internal (comment based) class documentation to keep track of the changes made to the individual classes. Thus, each class has its revisions log within the documentation, e.g.

```
%   Revision 1.0.0 (Author name, 19/08/2015)
%       Defined basic functionality.
%   Revision 1.0.1 (Author name, 19/10/2015)
%       Introduced abstract methods for the definition of the connection interface
%       in-situ.
```

I am interested in whether it is appropriate to keep the current system of tracking changes in the individual classes/files or I should abandon it and only specify the changes in the log messages before making a commit. 
My concerns regarding using the version control log system only is that it is unlikely to be as detailed as the internal system (i.e. typically a commit needs to be associated with multiple classes/files). On the other hand, it does feel very awkward to have two different revision numbers associated with one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comments just scream "put me in commit messages". Dates, author - these are all captured explicitly when committing. Plus, how do you plan to deal with situations where a change affects multiple classes?

(There's a lot of guides on how to write good ones ([1](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/), [2](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Writing-good-commit-messages), [3](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/5-useful-tips-for-a-better-commit-message)) regardles of what VCS is being used.)

As for *class* version numbers - there's really no point in doing so. What is this useful for? It's not like you can pick an choose which minor version of the class you'll be using. What *should* be versioned is the entire library/application, and versioned according to (preferably) [SemVer](http://semver.org/).